# How to make UserDetailsService throw custom exception when user is not found Spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, backend

I'm working on a Spring Boot application where I'm implementing user authentication using Spring Security. I have a custom `UserExistException` that extends `UsernameNotFoundException`, which I want to use to handle cases where a user does not exist in the system.

Here's an overview of my code:

1. I have a `CustomUserDetailsService` class that implements
   `UserDetailsService`. In this class, I check for the existence of a
   user by querying the database using a `UserManagerRepository`. If the
   user does not exist, I throw a `UserExistException`.

   ```
   @AllArgsConstructor
   @Service
   public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

   private final UserManagerRepository userManagerRepository;

   @SneakyThrows
   @Override
   public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

       UserManger user = userManagerRepository.findUserMangerByUserName(username)
               .orElseThrow(() -> new UserExistException("User with given username not found: " + username));

       Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities =
               user.getRoles()
                       .stream()
                       .map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getRoleName()))
                       .collect(Collectors.toSet());

       return new User(user.getUserName(),
               user.getPassword(),
               authorities);
   }
   }
   ```
2. I have configured exception handling using `@ControllerAdvice` to
   handle `UserExistException` and return an appropriate response.

   ```
   @ControllerAdvice
   public class GlobeControllerAdvice {
     @ExceptionHandler(UserExistException.class)
   public ResponseEntity<GlobalJsonResponseBody> generateUserExistException(Exception exception) {

       GlobalJsonResponseBody globalJsonResponseBody = getGlobalJsonResponseBody(exception);

       return new ResponseEntity<>(globalJsonResponseBody, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
   }
   }
   ```

This is `UserExistException` class

```
    public class UserExistException extends UsernameNotFoundException {
    public UserExistException(String message){
        super(message);
    }
   }
```

3. Additionally, I have a `SecurityConfiguration` class where I configure
   Spring Security. I have configured a `DaoAuthenticationProvider` and
   set `setHideUserNotFoundExceptions`(false) to ensure that
   `UserExistException` is not hidden.

   ```
   @AllArgsConstructor
   @EnableWebSecurity
   @Configuration
   @EnableMethodSecurity
   public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfiguration{

   private final JWTAuthEntryPoint authEntryPoint;

   private final JWTAuthFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter;
   private final CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;


   @Bean
   public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
   }

   @Bean
   public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration 
   configuration) 
   throws Exception {
   return configuration.getAuthenticationManager();
   }

   @Bean
   SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {

    httpSecurity.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                    .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/v1/auth/**").permitAll()
    .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
            .exceptionHandling(exceptionHandlingConfigurer -> exceptionHandlingConfigurer
                    .authenticationEntryPoint(authEntryPoint))

            .sessionManagement(session -> session
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS));

      httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter, 
      UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
      return httpSecurity.build();

    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    provider.setUserDetailsService(customUserDetailsService);
    provider.setHideUserNotFoundExceptions(false);
    return provider;
   }
   ```

Despite configuring everything as outlined previously, when a user is not found, the UserExistException is not being thrown as anticipated. Instead, a stack trace indicating the exception is being returned. In the mentioned class, I'm returning a GlobalJsonResponseBody object. However, the exception is only visible in the console rather than being returned as a JSON response.

```
com.kibuti.bishambabackend.Advice.Exceptions.UserExistException: User with given username not found: migambile21
    at com.kibuti.bishambabackend.Security.CustomUserDetailsService.lambda$loadUserByUsername$0(CustomUserDetailsService.java:30) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:403) ~[na:na]
    at com.kibuti.bishambabackend.Security.CustomUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(CustomUserDetailsService.java:30) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.kibuti.bishambabackend.Security.JWTAuthFilter.doFilterInternal(JWTAuthFilter.java:39) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
```

Any help will be appreciated,

Comment: You're saying the `UserExistException` is not thrown as expected and then post a stack trace that shows one being thrown.

Comment: A `UserExistException` you have an exception if a user exists? Mind blowing!

Comment: In the UserExistException class, I'm returning a GlobalJsonResponseBody object, which belongs to the JsonResponse class. However, the exception is only visible in the console instead of being returned as a JSON response.